# Submit form with 2 select fields to go to different pages

Tags: html, forms

I run a joomla site and would like to create an html form within an article that does the following:

```html
<form action="compare.html" method="post">

<select id="select1" name="select1" required="">
  <option value="A">OptionA</option>
  <option value="B">OptionB</option>
  <option value="C">OptionC</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="select2" required="">
  <option value="1">Option1</option>
  <option value="2">Option2</option>
  <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>

<input id="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

After selecting from the 2 dropdowns and submitting the form, the user should go to a page based on the selected options.  E.g.

OptionA + Option1  --> goes to page_97.html

OptionA + Option2  --> goes to page_451.html

OptionA + Option3  --> goes to page_13.html

OptionB + Option1  --> goes to page_77.html

and so on.

I was hoping this could be done in pure html or with some simple JS (I'm a newbie to js,php)?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Stackoverflow is best when you submit your attempt at the problem. This is doable with some simple js and without the use of a form. Research how to use the .value attribute of an element in JS, use that to redirect the user when the button is pressed. Give that a go and come back with an attempt! Good luck!

Comment: I don't see how it can be done in pure html. Your options are javascript as mentions by JCooke, or do the evaluation on the server side and redirect (or forward depending on the server side technology you use) from there to the target page.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution which works, but I am sure this could be optimized.

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1" required="" oninput="join_names();">
  <option value="">=== SELECT ===</option>
  <option value="A">OptionA</option>
  <option value="B">OptionB</option>
  <option value="C">OptionC</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="select2" name="select2" required="" oninput="join_names();">
  <option value="">=== SELECT ===</option>
  <option value="1">Option1</option>
  <option value="2">Option2</option>
  <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="compareButton" class="float-left submit-button">COMPARE</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var urlMap = {
    "default" : "/default.html",
    "A1"      : "/page_97.html",
    "A2"      : "/page_451.html",
    "A3"      : "/page_13.html"
    "A3"      : "/page_77.html"
   }

   function join_names() {
    var input_select1 = document.getElementsByName('select1')[0].value;
    var input_select2 = document.getElementsByName('select2')[0].value;
    var var_select12 = concatenate(input_select1, input_select2);
    var var_select12_url = getMapValue(urlMap,var_select12);
    document.getElementById("compareButton").onclick = function () {
       window.location.href = var_select12_url;
    };
   }

   function concatenate(string_one, string_two) {
    return string_one+string_two;
   }

   function getMapValue(obj, key) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return obj[key];
    } else { 
      return obj['default']; 
    }
   }
  
  </script>
```